# Is it possible to change an Ultracombo column caption

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, display, ultracombo

In vb.net, I have `ultragrids`, and I know with these it is possible to change the captions of a column (say, from `first_name` to `First Name`). On another window, I also have an `UltraCombo` (the `combobox` equivalent). When the down arrow is clicked to load the list, the only column displayed is `Supplier_Name`. Is there a way to rename this column, to remove the _?

The `Ultracombo` is called `cmbSuppCode`, and I've tried

```
cmbSuppCode.DisplayLayout 
'couldn't find anything

cmbSuppCode.Cells

'Also nothing
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the same way you do for an UltraGrid

```
 cmbSuppCode.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns(0).Header.Caption = "Supplier Name"
```

Of course the index for Bands and for Columns are assumed to be the Index for the first (or probably unique) band and for the first Column inside that band